# "No Such Element Error" in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem that i make test program using selenium on python
Step

1. connect Search Site.
2. random click
3. back
4. input keyword1 and search (driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#query'))
5. random click
6. back
7. input keyword2 and search  <= error (driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#query'))

i don't understand both same element(#query), why 2nd is only error.
please, guide to me.

step 4, 6 is absolutely same script

```
# connect main(portal site)
     :           :

# random click (news area)
log('news area random click!!')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.id_news li.ut_item a').click()
log('3sec delay')
time.sleep(3)

# move main(back)
log('move main')
driver.back()
time.sleep(2)

# input keyword1
log('input keyword1 : ' + keyword1)
element = driver.find_element_by_id('query') # is working very well
element.send_keys(keyword1)
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(3) 

# random click
log('news click !!!!!')
try:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('section.sp_nnews ul.list_news li a').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    # if not exists news area
    log("blog click!!!")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('section.sp_ntotal ul.lst_total li a').click()

time.sleep(2) # TODO : 17sec 

# move main again
log('move main')
driver.back()
time.sleep(5)

# input keyword2
log('input keyword2 : ' + keyword2)
element = driver.find_element_by_id('query') # is not working :( 
element.send_keys(keyword2)
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Share Html code

Comment: @KishanPatel here is code. please review it.

Comment: Few points you need to see. Try to manually do the same step and see that while 2nd click the same `id` i.e. query prevails or id is changed. Another thing try to put some `wait` before the second click and see whether it is clickable or not.

Comment: @KishanPatel :) Thank you very much. I mistake. as you say, manually did step. 2nd element name is different. I spent many time this issue. Thanks

Comment: Great @Bruce.Kwon  . HAPPY LEARNING :-)